# How do I proceed with this merge and fork/branch?

Tags: git

[image: Branch Diagram]

*(Diagram 1)*

At a past commit, I created a Foo branch and made some significant progress on the Foo feature.

Then I checked out main and began developing a Bar feature, so both branches share the same common ancestor. Later I went back to Foo and developed it further and realized that I wanted to take the progress in a different direction.

*(Diagram 2)*

I would like to achieve the second diagram: the goal is to checkout main, then incorporate both Foo and Bar (order not specific). Semantically I called it a fork because I want to go in a new direction with the project but it's really just a branch that gets all the latest progress.

Both Foo and Bar features certainly have edits to the same files, with possible conflicts.

And the final note is that the "Fork" branch does not need the itemized commits from Foo and Bar branches, just the progress. I think I need to *squash*?

How do I proceed with creating the new Fork branch and getting all of the progress from the features?

Comment: My guess is that I: checkout main, create Fork branch, merge squash Foo, merge squash Bar, then ideally somehow squash Foo merge with Bar merge... but given what I know of Git maybe need to keep these separate.

Comment: So you are ready to abandon the original Foo and Bar and just make your new topology? Then just rebase Bar onto Foo, and presto!, Foo _is_ your fork branch (and you can rename it `fork` if you want).

Comment: I would like to keep Foo and Bar as "abandoned" and clearly convey that Fork is not a feature branch of Foo.

Comment: "Clearly convey" is your problem: you need a branch name that does that, and coming up with a convention for it is entirely arbitrary. — To keep `foo` and `bar` as dead ends, just keep branch names for them.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a branch name for the old bar to hold its place:

```
git branch old-bar
```

Now, rebase `bar` onto `foo` and then rename `bar` to `fork`. First you'll need to determine the point where `bar` branched off of `main`:

```
git merge-base main bar
```

Write down the first digits of the SHA number of the result. Now:

```
git rebase --onto foo <SHA> bar
git branch -m fork
```

Finally, rename `old-bar` back to `bar`:

```
git branch -m old-bar bar
```